# Integrating a solution of NDSolve into table

Tags: differential-equations

So I am working with a set of three coupled DEs that  I numerically solve.  This is simple enough

```
NDSolve[{N1'[t] == -R1[ef]*N1[t] + b1*Γ0*N2[t], 
         N2'[t] == +R1[ef]*N1[t] - Γ0*N2[t] , 
         N3'[t] == b2*Γ0*N2[t] - Γ0/2 N3[t], 
         N1[0] == .65, N2[0] == 0, N3[0] == 0}, 
         {N1, N2, N3}, {t, 0, 300}]
```

Then I integrate my `N3` function (times `t`)

```
NIntegrate[t*Evaluate[N2[t] /. s], {t, 0, 300}]
```

In my DE's I have `R=-Log[1-ef]` , so what I want to know is how can I make a table (or anything) that will go  through, solve this and calculate that integral as a function of `ef`?

Thanks

Comment: Check out `ParametricNDSolve`. You will probably get a more complete answer if you provide a definition for `R`.

Comment: I would just add N4'[t] == t N2[t], N4[0] == 0 to your NDSolve call.

Comment: This table thing is making me confused. Can you clarify?

Comment: @MMM esentially I want a plot of the integral as a function of ef.  I figured a table would be best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method I**

With some valuable input from @halirutan, we will be able to integrate outside `ParametricNDSolve` and plot the resulting function,

```
b1 = 1; Γ0 = 2; b2 = 1;
R1 = -Log[1 - ef]
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{N1'[t] == -R1*N1[t] + b1*Γ0*N2[t], 
   N2'[t] == +R1*N1[t] - Γ0*N2[t], 
   N3'[t] == b2*Γ0*N2[t] - Γ0/2 N3[t], 
   N1[0] == .65, N2[0] == 0, N3[0] == 0},
   {N1, N2, N3}, {t, 0, 300}, {ef}]
Table[NIntegrate[t*N2[ef][t] /. sol, {t, 0, 300}], {ef, 0.1, 0.5, 0.1}]
```

> {1463.78, 2935.9, 4426.87, 5950.87, 7528.18}

```
ListLinePlot[%, DataRange -> {0.1, 0.5}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

**Method II**

Considering, @CarlWoll suggestion, we can get the same result as we have from method I.

```
sol1 = ParametricNDSolve[{N1'[t] == -R1*N1[t] + 
     b1*Γ0*N2[t], 
   N2'[t] == +R1*N1[t] - Γ0*N2[t], 
   N3'[t] == b2*Γ0*N2[t] - Γ0/2 N3[t], 
   N1[0] == .65, N2[0] == 0, N3[0] == 0, N4'[t] == t N2[t], 
   N4[0] == 0}, {N1, N2, N3, N4}, {t, 0, 300}, {ef}];

f[ef_] = (N4[ef][t] /. sol1 /. t -> 300 - N4[ef][t] /. sol1 /. t -> 0);

Table[Evaluate[f[ef]], {ef, 0.1, 0.5, 0.1}]
```

> {1463.78, 2935.9, 4426.87, 5950.87, 7528.18}

**Method III**

```
sol2[ef_] := 
 NDSolve[{N1'[t] == -(-Log[1 - ef])*N1[t] + b1*Γ0*N2[t],
    N2'[t] == (-Log[1 - ef])*N1[t] - Γ0*N2[t], 
   N3'[t] == b2*Γ0*N2[t] - Γ0/2 N3[t], 
   N1[0] == .65, N2[0] == 0, N3[0] == 0, N4'[t] == t N2[t], 
   N4[0] == 0}, {N1, N2, N3, N4}, {t, 0, 300}];

f[ef_] = N4[t] /. (sol2 /@ {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5}) /. t -> 300
```

> {{1463.78}, {2935.9}, {4426.87}, {5950.87}, {7528.18}}